# how to create setup files in c#

Tags: c#, setup-project

i like to setup for my project i did my project in Microsoft visual studio c#.net 2008, where i have start for that

Comment: you wanna add some more detail:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for an installer you can use the following free tools, if you want to pay, install shield is good:

Built into VS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173084(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked(VS.80).aspx

Other free tools:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

http://www.installjammer.com/

Install shield:

http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installshield.htm

Wise:

http://www.wise.com/Products/Installations/WiseInstallerEvaluations.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised noone has mentioned this yet:

[Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Open source, from Microsoft. (Yes, you read that right).

Free to use, yet very capable (used to create the Microsoft Office 2007 installer).

Based on commandline tools, so easily integrated into a build system.

My speculation: Since Rob Mensching (the primary author) has just moved into the Visual Studio team at Microsoft, this is likely to be directly supported (in some form) in the version of Visual Studio following 2010.

Update: An interesting [interview with Rob Mensching on Hanselminutes](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=213). On the show, Rob talks about how WiX is more than 10 years old, though the first public release was April 5, 2004.

Comment: @Bevan The reason I didn't bring it up is that I wanted to provide products that have been around a bit longer with better support and information. Wix hasn't been around long and there have been quite a few issues including the installer for office... but the OP could play if he'd like.

Comment: WiX has been around for a decade - that's quite a while in this business. I've updated my answer to link to a Jan 2010 Hanselminutes episode where Rob Mensching talks about the history and development of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a new [Setup and Deployment project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx3b589t%28VS.80%29.aspx) to your solution. Here is a [nice step by step instructions](http://www.fordevs.com/2009/07/steps-to-create-setup-and-deployment-project-in-dot-net-vs-2008.html).

Note: Which version of VS are you using? I am not sure whether this project type is available in Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) with [ISTool](http://www.istool.org/) (both are free) to create setup for my .NET C# applications.

Play around with ISTool and simply include your application files into the setup. Then configure to Download and install .NET redistributable and other components when required.